# how would you consider an offer of 8000 shekels (2460 USD) in Israel for a postdoc position?

Tags: postdocs, physics, salary, multidisciplinary, israel

**Hi, how would you consider an offer of around 8000 shekels (ca 2400 Euros or 2460 US Dollars) in Israel for a postdoc position?**

**A bit of context:** it would be a 3rd postdoc, applicant's age 36 yo, with international experience (4 countries), including R&D in multinational corporations and a second master degree (I mean in addition to bachelor, master and PhD).

**Note 1:** the first offer was around 6,100 shekels per month. Then, it became around 8,000 shekels per month.

**Note 2:** According to the website Glassdoor, the average monthly salary of a PhD student in Israel is 8,047 shekels per month (Ref.1) , while the average monthly salary of a postdoc is 10,489 shekels per month (Ref.2).

**Note 3:** From April 2022, the minimum monthly wage in Israel would be 5,400 shekels per month (Ref.3), while the average monthly salary for Israel would be 11,667 shekels per month (Ref.4) (in September 2021).

**EDIT --> Note 4:** As far as I understood, the contract would be for a trial period (up to 6 months), and, based on achievements/performance, the contract would be extended to "several years" (and I guess still as postdoc, but just my guess)..

Any thought is very welcome!

References:

- (Ref.1):
  https://www.glassdoor.it/Salaries/israel-phd-student-salary-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN119_KO7,18.htm?countryRedirect=true
- (Ref.2):
  https://www.glassdoor.it/Salaries/israel-postdoctoral-salary-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN119_KO7,19.htm?countryRedirect=true
- (Ref.3):
  https://www.timesofisrael.com/minimum-wage-to-increase-gradually-to-nis-6000-by-2025/
- (Ref.4):
  [https://www.timesofisrael.com/average-wage-in-israel-dips-slightly-as-economic-recoverycontinues/#:~:text=The%20average%20monthly%20salary%20for,from%20the%20COVID%2D19%20pandemic](https://www.timesofisrael.com/average-wage-in-israel-dips-slightly-as-economic-recoverycontinues/#:%7E:text=The%20average%20monthly%20salary%20for,from%20the%20COVID%2D19%20pandemic).

Comment: Note that 8000NIS scholarship is tax-free (while the average of 11k you state is before tax). In STEM fields, postdocs in Israel commonly get ~10,000NIS, Phd students ~8500, MS.c Students ~7000. In non-STEM fields there are less funding options and the amounts might be smaller.

Comment: @RanG. please note that it is not acceptable to use scholarships to replace working contracts, especially at the PostDoc level.

Comment: Would you please state the field?

Comment: Thanks @RanG. for your comment. However, I do not understand why you assume that 8000 NIS is (i) a scholarship and (ii) tax-free. I/we do not even know if it is a scholarship and/or tax-free. Also, in case it was a scholarship, I do not understand why it would not be a regular contract for regular worker (i.e. not a scholarship). Indeed, as far as I know, scholarships are generally for students (right?). Again, many thanks for your comment!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, very interesting! @Nobody, the field would be multidisciplinary / physics

Comment: To obtain an estimate, compare your current city and salary with the potential future salary and city here: https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/

Comment: I assume it is a (tax-free) scholarship, because this is the most common method for paying a student/postdoc in Israel. 99% of the students/postdoc positions are paid that way. But certainly, you should verify this with your host, maybe their funds are of the 1%. Last, it is tax-free by Israeli laws. However, if your own citizenship imposes other rules and there is no tax-treaty, then things might be different for you.

Comment: This seems like an awful offer, but it really depends on your personal circumstances.  The pay is very low and the contract duration is very short.  I was paid more as a first year PhD student, and that's a long time ago.

Comment: @RanG. Thank you for commenting... Talking to some Israeli friends I understood that there are not many fundings in Israel for research and this is the reason why many people end up in doing research abroad.... However, I still think, but maybe someone will make me change idea, that offering, as initial offer an amount very close to the minimum wage (i.e. 6100 shekels per month), and around 2000 shekels less than the average PhD salary is not fair

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist thanks a lot for your comment.... Looks like you did the PhD in Israel... If yes, it is very relieving to see that someone who did the PhD there could confirm that such offered salary (6,100 shekels per month first and 8,000 shekels per month after) would be similar or even less than for a PhD student.... This is unbelievable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> an offer of around 8000 shekels
>
> average monthly salary for Israel would be 11,667 shekels per month

If the average salary is a realistic value, I think it is a very good offer, **if and only if** one of these two conditions is true:

- it allows you to get an unlimited visa for working in Israel and in the following 2-3 months you find an average position with an average salary
- accepting the position you are guaranteed you will have a professorship or at least permanent employment afterwards (and you are 100% sure you would accept such a professorship/permanent contract).

Otherwise it is just exploitation: you are doing independent research work as a PostDoc and you are paid less than the average worker in a country? That's despicable, such behavior should not be promoted nor accepted and it should be called out. Please name at least the field and the University.

You are doing your 3rd PostDoc, probably in a 3rd different country: what are your motivations? what is your plan A? what is your plan B?

Comment: I am a hard time understanding what you are saying in this answer. What makes you think there would be a guarantee of a professorship afterwards??

Comment: @xLeitix In short: I am only saying this offer is appalling, even more considering the first offer was around 6,100 shekels per month, unless there are future benefits attached. I am in no way thinking there is a guarantee of professorship afterwards, but it may be the case as such kind of offer is(was) possible in other countries.

Comment: Hmm, ok. It seems to me if there were substantial additional benefits to the position OP would have probably mentioned them, but I retract my downvote.

Comment: Hello @EarlGrey, thanks for your comments! 

Please see my "EDIT --> Note 4" about future perspectives.. The contract would be for a trial period (max 6 months) and, based on the achievements, the contract would be extended for "several years" (not specified)....

Comment: @EarlGrey: About your first point: I do not know if there will be an "unlimited visa for working in Israel", and I do not know if "in the following 2-3 months you find an average position with an average salary". As far as I remember, none talked about possible changes in the salary for the postdoc after the trial period.

Comment: @EarlGrey: about your second point: As far as I remember, none talked about a possible professorship after the trial period (up to 6 months)... only about a contract for "several years"...

Comment: About "you are doing independent research work as a PostDoc and you are paid less than the average worker in a country?", I can say what I found on internet, the same references I posted, i.e. the offer would be around 8,000 shekels per month, the average monthly salary for Israel would be 11,667 shekels per month. But also, I would remind you that the first offer was around 6,100 shekels per month, i.e. almost 1/2 of the average monthly salary for Israel (11,667 shekels per month), and not that far from the minimum monthly wage in Israel (5,400 shekels per month).

Comment: @EarlGrey: About "You are doing your 3rd PostDoc, probably in a 3rd different country: what are your motivations? what is your plan A? what is your plan B?"... I would prefer not to comment in this regard... but thanks for asking! :)

Comment: @EarlGrey: In addition, an offer around 8,000 shekels per month would be, according to Glassdoors, the average monthly salary of a PhD student in Israel is 8,047 shekels per month (Ref.1). Therefore, does this offer look like for a PhD student instead of an offer for a 3rd postdoc worker?

Comment: @limone Regarding salary increase: what i meant is that you can take that offer, start working in Israel and then get out of the academia and find a better salary (and another job). That is connected to my question about your motivations: if you plan to stay in the academia, in general it is a good idea to apply for your own fundings, especially after PhDs, to show you can be a research manager (professors are unfortunately required to be manager, too), if you enjoy research ... it is time to look for a research position, either in research industry or in a research public body.

Comment: @limone it is up to you, we cannot decide for yourself if working (underpaid) several years as a postdoc is meaningful or not. It maybe the best option you aim for, the only one or whatever. Purely money-wise, it is a bad offer unless you get one of the two benefits I listed in the answer.

Comment: Given the state of the world, this is very likely OP's plan B. Plan A is "PANIC!!!1".

Comment: @Lodinn Given the state of the World (nuclear power occupying foreign land) I really hope this is plan Z ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_occupation_of_the_West_Bank#:~:text=The%20Israeli%20occupation%20of%20the,continues%20to%20the%20present%20day.

Comment: "I am only saying this offer is appalling"  You should edit the answer so it actually says that.

Comment: I agree with @AnonymousPhysicist.... I accepted the answer, but it is not extremely clear...@EarlGray: I mean, you wrote "I think it is a very good offer, if and only if" and then "I am only saying this offer is appalling"...... Please just state clearly if the offer is very good or very bad (looks like you want to say "it is very bad", except in case that two conditions can be met...but still it remains a bad offer, or something like that, right or wrong ?)

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist "it is a very good offer, if and only if  [...] Otherwise it is just exploitation" I cannot be clearer than this.

Comment: @EarlGrey Yes you can.  For example, replace the sentence with "This offer is exploitation unless one of these conditions is true:"

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist thanks!

Comment: EarlGrey I agree with @AnonymousPhysicist here. You *can* certainly be clearer. Starting an answer with a sentence that contains "this is a very good offer" simply does not communicate "this is bad offer", even if you add a lot of unrealistic conditions to it. Why not write "This is a terrible offer unless the (highly unlikely) following things are true:"?